# appending to current url angular on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic project that I want to append '/room' to the current url on the click of a button. This is in a template that is the view for many pages. I want to add /room to the end of each url. Ive tried many things and would love some help.

I am not using states because this is a deep nested view and need to use the change the URL. thanks

```
<button onclick="$location.path() + '/room'> Add /room to url </button >
```

Comment: No its not. Totally different.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/21328170/3279156

Comment: thanks but none of those work given how deep this state is and its not hosted on a server so the code wouldnt work with ios and android(files paths).. thats why I just want to append to the current